# Passing custom variable in iterator function in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I need to call a method for each item in the object with custom args.

```
var data2 = {
    "prop1":[{"foo":"val11"},{"bar":"val12"}],
    "prop2":[{"foo":"val21"},{"bar":"val22"}]
    }

function processData(data2){
  for(key in data2){
    _.each(data2[key],iterator,this);
  }
}

function iterator(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.key) // need value of 'key' here.
}

processData(data2);
```

Another way of doing the same is :

```
function processData(data2){
  for(key in data2){
    _.each(data2[key],function(data,index,list){
            iterator(data,key);
    });
  }
}

function iterator(data,key){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(key) // need value of 'key' here.
}
```

**Is there any simpler/cleaner way to achieve the same results? Or any other function that does the same thing?**

Answer (score 0):

How about this? `_.bind` is useful for you.

```
function processData(data2){
  _.mapObject(data2,function(v,k){
      _.each(v,_.bind(iterator, {key:k}))
  })
}
```

You can access key via `this.key` in `iterator` function. But for purity, I recommand getting key via arguments.

---

**Update**

More recommanded way is

```
function processData(data2){
  _.mapObject(data2,function(v,k){
      _.each(v,iterator.bind(null,k))
  })
}

function iterator(key,data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(key)
}
```

It keeps purity of `iterator` function.